# How to return text for an individual correct or wrong answer state in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have created a basic quiz.

When the user clicks the correct answer I want to return a text telling them that their answer was correct / wrong. At the moment every time the user selects a correct answer my `correct` or `wrong` text appears in every `questionBox`.

The expected behaviour I would like is for my text of `correct` or `wrong` to appear only when the user clicks the correct/ wrong answer and only in the box of the question they are answering. Right now it appears in all and changes in all every time the user clicks...

Please can someone explain the logic to me so that this doesn't happen?

Am I making sense? Let me know...

container:

```
class QuizBee extends Component {
  state = {
    qBank: [],
    score: 0,
    responses: 0,
    right: ""
  };

  getQuestions = () => {
    quizService().then(question => {
      this.setState({
        qBank: question,
        score: 0,
        responses: 0
      });
    });
  };

  computeAnswer = (answer, correct,questionId) => {
    if (answer === correct) {
      this.setState({
        score: this.state.score + 1,
        right: "correct!!"
      });

    } else {
      this.setState({
        right: "sorry wrong!"
      });

    }

    this.setState({
      responses: this.state.responses < 5 ? this.state.responses + 1 : 5
    });
    console.log(questionId);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuestions();
  };



  render() {

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="title">Quiz Me</div>
          {this.state.qBank.length > 0 &&
            this.state.responses < 5 &&
             this.state.qBank.map(quest => {

                  const { question, answers, correct, questionId } = quest;

                  return (

                   <QuestionBox
                     question={question}
                     options={answers}
                     key={questionId}
                     correct={correct}
                     selected={answer => this.computeAnswer(answer, correct, questionId)}
                     right={this.state.right}
                   />
                   )
                })}

                {this.state.responses === 5 ?
                  <h2><ResultCard score={this.state.score} getQuestions={this.getQuestions}/></h2>
                  : null}
            </div>
        );
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(<QuizBee />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

questionBox which houses each question:

```
import React, {useState}  from "react";


const QuestionBox = ({question, options, questionId, correct, selected, right}) => {

  const [answers, setAnswerFunction ] = useState(options);
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <div className="question"> {question} </div>
      {answers.map((answer,index) => {
        return(
          <button key={index} className="answerBtn" type="button" onClick={() => {
            setAnswerFunction([answer]);
            selected(answer);
          }} >
            {answer}
          </button>
        );
      }
      )}
      <div className="question"> {right} </div>
    </div>
  )
};
export default QuestionBox;
```

questions:

```
const qBank = [
  {
    question:
      "Virgin Trains, Virgin Atlantic and Virgin Racing, are all companies owned by which famous entrepreneur?   ",
    answers: ["Richard Branson", "Alan Sugar", "Donald Trump", "Bill Gates"],
    correct: "Richard Branson",
    questionId: "099099"
  },
  {
    question:
      'Where is the train station "Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch"?',
    answers: ["Wales", "Moldova", "Czech Republic", "Denmark"],
    correct: "Wales",
    questionId: "183452"
  },
 {
    question: "What's the name of Batman's  parents?",
    answers: [
      "Thomas & Martha",
      "Joey & Jackie",
      "Jason & Sarah",
      "TodWhat is the most common surd & Mira"
    ],
    correct: "Thomas & Martha",
    questionId: "333247"
  }

];

export default (n = 5) =>
  Promise.resolve(
    qBank.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, n)
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be using a state to keep track of the selected response message(correct/wrong) in QuestionBox itself.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const QuestionBox = ({ question, options, correct, right, incrementScore }) => {
  const computeAnswer = answer => {
    if (answer === correct) {
      setResponse("correct");
      incrementScore();
    } else {
      setResponse("sorry wrong!");
    }
  };
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");
  const [answers, setAnswerFunction] = useState(options);
  return (
    <div className="questionBox">
      <div className="question"> {question} </div>
      {answers.map((answer, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={index}
            className="answerBtn"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              setAnswerFunction([answer]);
              computeAnswer(answer);
            }}
          >
            {answer}
          </button>
        );
      })}
      <div className="question"> {response} </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default QuestionBox;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-bash-qeqfe?file=/src/QuestionBox.jsx:0-959

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, so gutted I couldn't think of this but it makes perfect sense THANK YOU!

Comment: Could you see any reason why `incrementScore();` in the `questionBox` component is not being called in the higher component? I `console.logged` in the `if` statement to see if it was hitting the function when the answer was correct which it is, but this does not then call the function in the component above where i am using  it  in the higher component e.g. `incrementScore = () => {
    this.setState({
      responses: this.state.responses < 5 ? this.state.responses + 1 : 5
    });
  };`

Answer (score 2):

it happens because **right** state is the same for all children, and not unique for each one. Once given children picks an answer, the **right** global state changes, hence all children changes.

@gemhar approach is a good one, it lets each children to compare its current answer state with the right option. also moves the text options to the QuestionBox component, where it should belong.

Tip: rewrite this:

```
                {this.state.responses === 5 ?
              <h2><ResultCard score={this.state.score} getQuestions={this.getQuestions}/></h2>
              : null}
```

to this:

```
                { this.state.responses === 5 &&
              <h2><ResultCard score={this.state.score} getQuestions={this.getQuestions}/></h2> }
```

if the first part evaluates as false it wont render the second part

Comment: thank you for the explanation that makes more sense now. I will replace the code you suggested too.  `&&` is using the AND operator and  boolean logic right?

Comment: yes that's right. it's a common use case for `&&` in React. it wont evaluate the second part if the first one is already falsey.